# How to set limits in a matplotlib patchcollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am using the following piece of code to display a network where the edges are colored according to their weight:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

seed = 13648  # Seed random number generators for reproducibility
G = nx.random_k_out_graph(10, 3, 0.5, seed=seed)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=seed)

node_sizes = [3 + 10 * i for i in range(len(G))]
M = G.number_of_edges()
edge_colors = range(2, M + 2)
edge_alphas = [(5 + i) / (M + 4) for i in range(M)]
cmap = plt.cm.plasma

nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=node_sizes, node_color="indigo")
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G,
    pos,
    node_size=node_sizes,
    arrowstyle="->",
    arrowsize=10,
    edge_color=edge_colors,
    edge_cmap=cmap,
    width=2,
)
# set alpha value for each edge
for i in range(M):
    edges[i].set_alpha(edge_alphas[i])

pc = mpl.collections.PatchCollection(edges, cmap=cmap)
pc.set_array(edge_colors)
plt.colorbar(pc)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

It yields the following graph:

[image: Graph with default colormap limit settings]

I want to manually change the limits of the colormap. To do so I use:

```
pc.set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=60)
```

It yields the following graph:

[image]

The problem is, that the colorbar does change according to the limits I set, but the color of the edges is exactly the same, which means they are displaying incorrect values. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve it, you can set limits in draw_networkx_edges as

```
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    G,
    pos,
    node_size=node_sizes,
    arrowstyle="->",
    arrowsize=10,
    edge_color=edge_colors,
    edge_cmap=cmap,
    width=2,
    edge_vmin=0, edge_vmax=60
)
```